# Google Sheets query formula: using a cell reference as a string

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a query formula in google sheets using where/contains to find values in another sheet that correspond with the text in column A of the original sheet. Since there will be hundreds or thousands of columns, I don't want to manually enter the text to search for in each row: is there a way to input the text of another cell as a variable?

For reference, the formula structure is:

=Sum(query('SheetName'!A:D, "SELECT C Where B Contains 'text1'"))

I'd like to replace 'text1' with a cell reference so I don't have to actually input it.

There is also likely a way better way to do this overall, but this is what I've got so far.  thanks!

Comment: use double quotes and ampersands to refer to cell
query('SheetName'!A:D, "SELECT C Where B Contains ' "&DifferentSheetName!A1&" ' ",0)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Show your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation to build the query statement, like this:

```
=query( 
  SheetName!B2:C, 
  "select sum(C) 
   where B contains '" & trim(A2) & "' 
   label sum(C) '' ", 
  0 
)
```

Comment: Where does this query reference the value of `text1` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: The OP wrote: "I'd like to replace 'text1' with a cell reference". The formula references a cell.

Comment: OK, I get it - the user enters their "search" term in Cell A2 of the same sheet in which the query is entered.